# rdesktop session to RDP server hangs

Tags: rdesktop

I have noticed that when I leave my RDP session to Windows server open for a night, then in the morning session has hanged. For example I can't even type anything into password box:

[image]

According to `ps` the status of `rdesktop` process is following:

```
$ ps -o pid,ppid,state,time,command -fp 26638
  PID  PPID S     TIME COMMAND
26638 26637 S 00:00:01 rdesktop -E -g 1920x1100 10.20.20.6 -a 32 -r clipboard:PRIMARYCLIPBOARD -r disk:windows /home/martin/windows -z -K
$
```

However, under normal conditions, it is pretty much the same:

```
$ ps -o pid,ppid,state,time,command -fp 30179
  PID  PPID S     TIME COMMAND
30179 30178 S 00:00:02 rdesktop -E -g 1920x1100 10.20.20.6 -a 32 -r clipboard:PRIMARYCLIPBOARD -r disk:windows /home/martin/windows -z -K
$
```

At first I thought that maybe my `iptables`/`netfilter` session times out, but this does not seem to be the reason because I inserted a rule which allows all the traffic from RDP server(10.10.10.1):

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --   10.20.20.6          anywhere
```

What might cause this timeout? Is it possible that this timeout comes from RDP server side?

Comment: Isn't your rdp server 10.20.20.6 not 10.10.10.1? Is NAT involved between client and server? What about power-saving settings on the Windows machine?

Comment: Is a VPN connection involved? If so, perhaps that one fails...

Comment: @rudimeier Thanks for pointing that out. I copied a wrong line from `iptables -L` output. I fixed the initial post. NAT is not involved and this Windows machine runs 24/7. However, I don't manage the RDP server so I'm not able to provide any details about that. @Jan There is no VPN.